# What is Difference Comparing Class Types in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, compare

```
public <T, V> void F1(T p1, V p2) {
    //Method 1
    if (p1.getClass() == p2.getClass()) {
    }

    //Method 2
    if (p1.getClass().equals(p2.getClass())) {
    }

    //Method 3
    if (p1.getClass().getName().equals(p2.getClass().getName())) {
    }
}
```

I want to compare the parameter's class,

Which method is more secure or is there any little bit difference in 3 usage?

Comment: I can't test it right now but it seems like the third method is flawed: two classes can have the same name in a different namespace.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Doesn't `getName()` method return fully qualified name of the class?

Comment: @RohitJain: [appearantly not](https://ideone.com/gnNcJO)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That class isn't in any package. What did you expect it to print?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: they do actually. obj.getClass().getName() returns com.test.MyClass

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Basically it's the `getSimpleName()` which doesn't give fully qualified name.

Comment: Ah indeed, looked past the lack of a package. My remark doesn't stand in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the three methods will do the same task. But ideally you should go with first approach. In fact, since `Class` doesn't override `equals()` method, it will anyways call `Object#equals()` method. And it makes sense also, as for every particular class, there is only a single class instance per classloader. So comparing them using `==` would be perfectly fine.

Also, I think if `p1` and `p2` correspond to the same class loaded by different classloaders, then the first two condition will be `false`, while the last one will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to check. You're three methods check three different things:

1. Check that the two instances of Class are **the same instance**
2. Check that the two instances of Class are instances **of the same Class**
3. Check that the two instances of Class are instances of two **classes with the same name** (not necessarily the same Class)